# I use react-router to navigate and url changed but components are not rendered

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

After I clicked the button with `useNavigate` to direct to another page, the url changed but the components are not rendered.

Here is my code. Maybe I have done something wrong. However, I follow the sample from the official tutorial of `react-router`. I wonder whether it is the incompatible of `react` and `react-router` version?

HomePage.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function HomePage() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const goTo = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    navigate("/page2");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="border-solid border-2 border-teal-700">
        first page
        <br/>
        <button type="button" onClick={goTo}>Page2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

Page2.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

function Page2() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="border-solid border-2 border-teal-700">
        second page
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Page2;
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import HomePage from './component/HomePage';

function App() {
  return (
    <HomePage></HomePage>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  RouterProvider
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Page2 from './component/Page2';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "page2",
        element: <Page2 />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

package.json

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
  "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
  "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
  "@types/node": "^16.18.22",
  "@types/react": "^18.0.31",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
  "localforage": "^1.10.0",
  "match-sorter": "^6.3.1",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
  "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
  "sort-by": "^1.2.0",
  "typescript": "^4.9.5",
  "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is rendering `Page2` as a ***nested*** child route from `"/"`.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "page2",
        element: <Page2 />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

So the `App` component would need to render an `Outlet` component for the nested routes to render their `element` content into. See [Outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets).

```
import React from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import HomePage from './component/HomePage';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <HomePage />
      <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But this means the `HomePage` component will be matched and rendered anytime one of the sub-routes is also matched and rendered. If this is not the intended design then you'll want to specify `"/page2"` as a ***sibling*** route, independent from `"/"`.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
  },
  {
    path: "page2",
    element: <Page2 />,
  },
]);
```